# Websphere MQ via JMS: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to make a simple JMS client application for Websphere MQ 7.5
I already have ".bindings" file with connection factory and destination, which I'm trying to connecto to. 
This is my simple Java code, that I'm trying to run on mac:

```
package com.company;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class Main {
    public static final String     cfLookup    = "TEST12";
    public static final String     icf         = "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory";
    static              String     url         = "file:///tmp/JNDI";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitialDirContext  ctx          = null;
        Destination myDest       = null;
        ConnectionFactory connFactory  = null;
        Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
        try {
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, icf);
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
            ctx = new InitialDirContext( environment );
            connFactory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup( cfLookup );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.setupDistHubTracing(WMQFactoryFactory.java:335)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.<init>(WMQFactoryFactory.java:305)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQFactoryFactory.java:186)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getFactoryInstance(WMQComponent.java:140)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:293)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:81)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:77)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

It's pretty obvious, that some other libraries are required, but none of those JAR file I got copying from Websphere MQ client installation seem to work. And also it feels kinda strange that some provider specific class is needed to make a query against JNDI. 
I already read a lot of topics at IBM and mqseries, but nothing helps. Any assistance would by higly appreciated.

Also with every run there is also a newly generated FDC file with more detailed information

```
----------------------------------START FFST------------------------------------
/Users/***/IdeaProjects/JmsSample/FFDC/JMSCC0001.FDC PID:640

                                    JMS Common Client First Failure Symptom Report


Product          :- IBM WebSphere MQ classes for JMS
Date/Time        :- Sat Feb 06 16:56:23 MSK 2016
System time      :- 1454766983855
Operating System :- Mac OS X
UserID           :- ***
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 25.72-b15

Source Class     :- JmsFactoryFactory
Source Method    :- getIntance(int)
ProbeID          :- XI001005
Thread           :- name=main priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@372f7a8d

                                      Data
                                      ----

|   connectionTypeName  :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
|   exception           :-  ExceptionDepth is 4
|   exception           :-  
|   |   Cause:1       :-  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
|   |   Cause:2       :-  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig
|   |   Cause:3       :-  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
|   |   Message:2     :-  com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig
|   |   Message:3     :-  com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
|   |   StackTrace:1  :-  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3314)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:283)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:81)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:77)
|   |       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
|   |       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
|   |       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:31)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
|   |   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.setupDistHubTracing(WMQFactoryFactory.java:335)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.<init>(WMQFactoryFactory.java:305)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQFactoryFactory.java:186)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getFactoryInstance(WMQComponent.java:140)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:157)
|   |       ... 19 more
|   |   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
|   |       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
|   |       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
|   |       ... 24 more
|   |   
|   |   StackTrace:2  :-  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.setupDistHubTracing(WMQFactoryFactory.java:335)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.<init>(WMQFactoryFactory.java:305)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQFactoryFactory.java:186)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getFactoryInstance(WMQComponent.java:140)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:157)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3314)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:283)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:81)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:77)
|   |       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
|   |       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
|   |       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:31)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
|   |   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
|   |       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
|   |       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
|   |       ... 24 more
|   |   
|   |   StackTrace:3  :-  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
|   |       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
|   |       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
|   |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.setupDistHubTracing(WMQFactoryFactory.java:335)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.<init>(WMQFactoryFactory.java:305)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQFactoryFactory.java:186)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getFactoryInstance(WMQComponent.java:140)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:157)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3314)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:283)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:81)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:77)
|   |       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
|   |       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
|   |       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
|   |       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:31)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   |       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
|   |   

                              Version information
                              -------------------

IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
7.5.0.3
p750-003-140123
Production

Common Services for Java Platform, Standard Edition
7.5.0.3
p750-003-140123
Production

Java Message Service Client
7.5.0.3
p750-003-140123
Production

WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
7.5.0.3
p750-003-140123
Production



                                  Stack trace
                                  -----------

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
|   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:1959)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1898)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1787)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1660)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:214)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3314)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:283)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:81)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:77)
|       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
|       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
|       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
|       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
|       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:31)
|       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
|   

                            Property Store Contents
                            -----------------------

All currently set properties
|   awt.toolkit                    :-  sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
|   file.encoding                  :-  UTF-8
|   file.encoding.pkg              :-  sun.io
|   file.separator                 :-  /
|   ftp.nonProxyHosts              :-  local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
|   gopherProxySet                 :-  false
|   http.nonProxyHosts             :-  local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
|   idea.launcher.bin.path         :-  /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/bin
|   idea.launcher.port             :-  7533
|   java.awt.graphicsenv           :-  sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
|   java.awt.printerjob            :-  sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
|   java.class.path                :-  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/IdeaProjects/JmsSample/out/production/JmsSample:/Users/vladimirpopov/IdeaProjects/JmsSample/com.ibm.mq.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/IdeaProjects/JmsSample/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/jms.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/jndi.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/fscontext.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/com.ibm.mq.defaultconfig.jar:/Users/vladimirpopov/Downloads/jar/providerutil.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar
|   java.class.version             :-  52.0
|   java.endorsed.dirs             :-  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
|   java.ext.dirs                  :-  /Users/vladimirpopov/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
|   java.home                      :-  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
|   java.io.tmpdir                 :-  /var/folders/v0/vk3bz2wn79q5_9qggqqf_ynh0000gn/T/
|   java.library.path              :-  /Users/vladimirpopov/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
|   java.runtime.name              :-  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
|   java.runtime.version           :-  1.8.0_72-b15
|   java.specification.name        :-  Java Platform API Specification
|   java.specification.vendor      :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.specification.version     :-  1.8
|   java.vendor                    :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vendor.url                :-  http://java.oracle.com/
|   java.vendor.url.bug            :-  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
|   java.version                   :-  1.8.0_72
|   java.vm.info                   :-  mixed mode
|   java.vm.name                   :-  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
|   java.vm.specification.name     :-  Java Virtual Machine Specification
|   java.vm.specification.vendor   :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vm.specification.version  :-  1.8
|   java.vm.vendor                 :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vm.version                :-  25.72-b15
|   line.separator                 :-  
|   
|   os.arch                        :-  x86_64
|   os.name                        :-  Mac OS X
|   os.version                     :-  10.10.5
|   path.separator                 :-  :
|   socksNonProxyHosts             :-  local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
|   sun.arch.data.model            :-  64
|   sun.boot.class.path            :-  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes
|   sun.boot.library.path          :-  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
|   sun.cpu.endian                 :-  little
|   sun.cpu.isalist                :-  
|   sun.io.unicode.encoding        :-  UnicodeBig
|   sun.java.command               :-  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.company.Main
|   sun.java.launcher              :-  SUN_STANDARD
|   sun.jnu.encoding               :-  UTF-8
|   sun.management.compiler        :-  HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
|   sun.os.patch.level             :-  unknown
|   user.country                   :-  US
|   user.dir                       :-  /Users/vladimirpopov/IdeaProjects/JmsSample
|   user.home                      :-  /Users/vladimirpopov
|   user.language                  :-  en
|   user.name                      :-  vladimirpopov
|   user.timezone                  :-  

                           WorkQueueMananger Contents
                           --------------------------

|   Current ThreadPool size      :-  0
|   Maintain ThreadPool size     :-  false
|   Maximum ThreadPool size      :-  -1
|   ThreadPool inactive timeout  :-  0

                               Runtime properties
                               ------------------

|   Available processors         :-  4
|   Free memory in bytes (now)   :-  107069912
|   Max memory in bytes          :-  1908932608
|   Total memory in bytes (now)  :-  128974848

                           Component Manager Contents
                           --------------------------

Common Services Components:
|   CMVC               :-  p750-003-140123
|   Class Name         :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.J2SEComponent
|   Component Name     :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se
|   Component Title    :-  Common Services for Java Platform, Standard Edition
|   Factory Class      :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.CommonServicesImplementation
|   Version            :-  7.5.0.3
|   inPreferenceTo[0]  :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2me

Messaging Provider Components:
|   CMVC             :-  p750-003-140123
|   Class Name       :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
|   Component Name   :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
|   Component Title  :-  IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
|   Factory Class    :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
|   Version          :-  7.5.0.3
```

Comment: This question gets bumped by Community periodically as there is no accepted answer. Can you review and if one of these answers helped you can you accept it. If none of them helped you could you provide a self answer with what your solution was? If you have questions on how to accept please comment back.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you can look inside the JAR files?  The MQ Java JAR file with that class is 'dhbcore.jar'.

Instead of selectively copying then using certain MQ JAR files (which is not supported by IBM), why don't you follow the [supported path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376217) IBM has laid out?

Answer (score 0):

Add dhbcore.jar in class path and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with WAS8 but I believe that the answer will be similar.

You'll have to reference the libs located in the `${was8Path}/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/` path.

I had a similar exception `**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/msg/client/commonservices/trace/Trace**` and I solved it by referencing the `${was8Path}/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.jar` library to the project.